# displaying data based on if condition in a birt report

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reporting, birt

I need to display few values based on `if condition` in the `birt report`.Is there any way to do that?
I'm using XML as a `datasource`, so if the tag is not empty i want to display it within the report.
 
this is the xml sample i need to add within my report

```
<wr:if><wr:out/></wr:if><wr:if><wr:out/></wr:if><wr:if><wr:out/></wr:if>
```

here the `<wr:out/>` corresponds to a tag in XML which i've used as a dataset.

I want to know how to display these data within the birt report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign the property visibility

```
<list-property name="visibility">
  <structure>
     <property name="format">all</property>
     <expression name="valueExpr" type="javascript">your evaluation here</expression>
  </structure>
</list-property>
```

When expression evaluates to true the the element is hidden.

Take a look at this tutorial

http://digiassn.blogspot.com.au/2007/03/birt-hide-report-table-when-no-data-is.html